# Insert a value at a NOT NULL column int in SQL Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent, insert

```
$add_v = new App\Models\HmsBbrCategory;
$add_v->id->max(id)+1;
$add_v->category_id->max(category_id)+1;
$add_v->category_name='Insert 1';
$add_v->category_description='Insert Desc';
$add_v->created_by='Me';
$add_v->created_datetime=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
$add_v->save();
```

[image: 1]

I need to have this eloquent inserting data into my table with my first two columns, id, category_id be added with auto increment, specifically, the highest value + 1.

my code above has the error:

```
Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError
Call to a member function max() on null
```

what can I at the "max()" for this to function as intended? any help would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: Do you really need category_id as well as the id?

Comment: yes i need both

Comment: Generally doing a max() + 1 is not particularly safe, what if 2 requests try and insert a record at the same time - they may both get the same id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have error in

```
$add_v->category_id->max(category_id)+1;
```

I think you need

```
$category=App\Models\HmsBbrCategory::orderByDesc('id')->first();
```

then

```
 $add_v->category_id=$category->id+1;
```